# how to get the certain list from a file with using a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently learning the beginner level of computer science in university. I am not really sure how to get certain information from the opened file... If any chance, Could anybody teach me how to do this code?

```
def get_month_temp(openfile, m):
  '''
  (file, int) -> listReturn a list of temperatures for the
  month mo for all years with data in
  open_file, where mo is an integer between
  0 and 12, representing January to December,
  respectively.
  >>>got_month_temp("temperature.csv", 1)
  [24.7, 16,1, 10.4, 21.5, 19.1, 14.0, 8.4, 11.2, 13.4, 22.5, 17.6, 20.4]
  '''
  openfile = open_temperature_file(filename)
```

This is the "temperature.csv" file I am talking about.

```
  Average monthly temperatures in Dubuque, Iowa, 
  January 1964 through december 1975, n=144

  24.7,25.7,30.6,47.5,62.9,68.5,73.7,67.9,61.1,48.5,39.6,20.0
  16.1,19.1,24.2,45.4,61.3,66.5,72.1,68.4,60.2,50.9,37.4,31.1
  10.4,21.6,37.4,44.7,53.2,68.0,73.7,68.2,60.7,50.2,37.2,24.6
  21.5,14.7,35.0,48.3,54.0,68.2,69.6,65.7,60.8,49.1,33.2,26.0
  19.1,20.6,40.2,50.0,55.3,67.7,70.7,70.3,60.6,50.7,35.8,20.7
  14.0,24.1,29.4,46.6,58.6,62.2,72.1,71.7,61.9,47.6,34.2,20.4
  8.4, 19.0,31.4,48.7,61.6,68.1,72.2,70.6,62.5,52.7,36.7,23.8
  11.2,20.0,29.6,47.7,55.8,73.2,68.0,67.1,64.9,57.1,37.6,27.7
  13.4,17.2,30.8,43.7,62.3,66.4,70.2,71.6,62.1,46.0,32.7,17.3
  22.5,25.7,42.3,45.2,55.5,68.9,72.3,72.3,62.5,55.6,38.0,20.4
  17.6,20.5,34.2,49.2,54.8,63.8,74.0,67.1,57.7,50.8,36.8,25.5
  20.4,19.6,24.6,41.3,61.8,68.5,72.0,71.1,57.3,52.5,40.6,26.2
```

Comment: and how does `"temperature.csv"` contents look like?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I just added the file of "temperature.csv". Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hi, thank you for your replying! yes, I am required to use for-loops! could you help me writing this program?

Comment: You should really learn how to do this on your own. Read the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on basic file usage.

Comment: Also, surely the integer must be between 0 and 11 or 1 and 12, but not 0 and 12...

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected output all temperature data for each month has lined up in vertical columns.
Use the following approach with `csv.reader` object, `split` function and *list comprehension*:

```
def get_month_temp(openfile, m):
    if m not in range(1, 13):
        raise ValueError('incorrect month number!')

    with open(openfile) as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',')
        lines = [l.strip().split(',')[m-1] for l in fh]
        print(lines)


get_month_temp("data/temperature.csv", 1)
```

The output:

```
['24.7', '16.1', '10.4', '21.5', '19.1', '14.0', '8.4', '11.2', '13.4', '22.5', '17.6', '20.4']
```